# rsync file duplication ignore is not working as expected

Tags: rsync, cp

I am confused with the working of rsync. Here is what I did and expected.

I created two folders named 'sbck' and 'dbck'.

#### **Scenario 1:**

I created a file named `a.txt` and created a copy of it using `cp -rp a.txt aa.txt`. I placed both the files in `sbck` folder. Next I did `rsync -rvch sbck/ dbck/`. This moved the both files into dbck.

***Question***: Since both a.txt and aa.txt are the same, why does rsync allow this copy? Shouldn't it just be one of the both only?

#### **Scenario 2:**

I created a file named `a.txt` and created a copy of it using `cp -rp a.txt aa.txt`. I placed both the files in `sbck` folder. Next, I did `cp -rp sbck/a.txt  dbck/`. Later, I did `rsync -rvch sbck/ dbck/`. This moved the `aa.txt` into dbck.

***Question***: Since both a.txt and aa.txt are the same, and I already moved a.txt to dbck. why does rsync allow aa.txt copy to dbck? How is -c exactly helping me in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what `-c` does. `rsync` does not do file deduplication, with or without the `-c` option. All `-c` does is change how `rsync` decides whether a file needs to be updated on the destination.

Suppose `sbck/a.txt` and `dbck/a.txt`, and you run `rsync -rvh sbck/ dbck/` (note: no `-c` option). What `rsync` does, is compare the size and modification time on those two files, and if they match it'll assume the files' contents match as well, and won't bother to copy `sbck/a.txt` to `dbck/a.txt`.

Now, suppose you run `rsync -rvch sbck/ dbck/` (with `-c` this time). This time, `rsync` will compute checksums of `sbck/a.txt` and `dbck/a.txt`, and use those (instead of their size and mod times) to determine whether the files are the same and hence the new contents of `sbck/a.txt` don't need to be copied to `dbck/a.txt`. It does not compare the checksum of `sbck/a.txt` to that of any other file in either the source or destination tree.

Comment: Thanks, I have understood What -c does now. But what exactly is happening in both Scenario 1 and 2, can you please explaining that too?

Comment: Hi, so basically rsync will copy based on size, modified time Or checksum, but only it does it by looking for the name of the file in the destination first? So, even if all parameters of the file stays exactly the same, still rsync will copy duplicate if the file being copied over has a different name?

Comment: `rsync` does not look for duplicates under other names. When syncing `sbck/aa.txt`, it *only* looks at whether there's already a matching file at `dbck/aa.txt`; it does not look for duplicates under other names, so the existence of a matching file at `dbck/a.txt` doesn't affect what it does to sync `sbck/aa.txt` at all. Similarly, if there was a matching file named `dbck/bb.txt`, it'd be completely ignored (unless you specified the `--delete` option or one of its variants, in which case `dbck/bb.txt` would be deleted).

Comment: BTW, you should understand that the basic goal of `rsync` is to make the destination match the source. This means that if the source directory has two identical files named `a.txt` and `aa.txt`, it should make the destination *also* contain two identical files named `a.txt` and `aa.txt`. The only reason `rsync` does any sort of duplicate detection at all is to avoid unnecessary transfers (it's designed to run over slow network links, so avoiding unnecessary data transfer is a secondary goal).